# How can I enable the lighttpd on startup in Ubuntu

Tags: server, xubuntu

How can I enable on startup/boot level in Ubuntu?

Which command should I use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable you can use:

```
sudo systemctl enable lighttpd
```

To get the status (to chekc if it is running or enabled)

```
sudo systemctl status lighttpd
```

Comment: Thanks 
How to check if it is running at boot level or not?